# Jenkinsfile groovy unable to use arguments in method

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

How do I call a method with arguments from a Jenkinsfile.

```
def upload_nightly_build(local_filename, remote_filename) 
{
    sh 'curl --output $local_filename http://someserver:8000/firmware/$remote_filename'
    sh 'curl -F upload_file=@$local_filename http://someserver:8000/frontend/file_upload_handler'
    sh 'rm $local_filename'
}

pipeline 
{
    agent 
    { 
        dockerfile 
        {
            dir 'dockerfiles'
            filename 'Dockerfile-integration.tests'
        }
    } 
    stages 
    {
        stage('upload binaries')
        {
            steps
            {
                dir ("firmware")
                {
                    upload_nightly_build('iobox-1024-nightly.bin', 'iobox-1024.bin')
                }
            }
        }      
    }
}
```

Tried so far

- encapsulate usage of arguments in method with braces
- define arguments as String
- define arguments with def
- used named arguments using Map

Whatever I try, in Jenkins console output I will always see

```
+ curl --output http://someserver:8000/firmware/
curl: no URL specified!
```

Answer (score 0):

Sigh... found it myself eventually..

```
    sh "curl --output $local_filename http://someserver:8000/firmware/$remote_filename"
```

Double quote the sh argument... I should've known...